# How to Sort and Label Lollipop Chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a lollipop chart that I would like to change the bars to descending order, and add data labels to. Anyone know would I go about doing this?
My data is here https://gofile.io/d/MpmZsy

```
ggplot(states, aes(x=state, y=count)) +
  geom_segment( aes(x=state, xend=state, y=0, yend=count), color="dodgerblue4") +
  geom_point( color="dodgerblue4", size=4, alpha=0.6) +
  theme_light() +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank()
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order of bars is controlled by factor levels of the states and adding data labels can be managed by `geom_text`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

states %>%
  arrange(count) %>%
  mutate(state = factor(state, unique(state))) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(x=state, y=count) +
  geom_segment( aes(x=state, xend=state, y=0, yend=count), color="dodgerblue4") +
  geom_point( color="dodgerblue4", size=4, alpha=0.6) +
  geom_text(aes(label = count), hjust = -1) + 
  theme_light() +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is perfect. I have one last question. Is it possible to change the color of the font of the state names to black?

Comment: You can add `axis.text.y = element_text(color = 'black')` in `theme`.